# PHP - Find exact value or value above from array

Tags: php, arrays, max

I have a nested array with valid numbers => data:-

```
$validData = array(array(1 => 'one data'),array(5 => '5 data'),array(15 => '15 data'),array(30 => 'thirty data'));
```

Let say I have a query value, $query = 14;

I want to first check if there's a 14, if not then go to the nearest option ABOVE.

I've been doing nearest item with max, array_keys and ranges. But, matching or going above for some reason I can't see the best way?

Comment: Sort the array, loop through the array remembering the previous item, if you're past the item, use the previous item...

Comment: Or, loop through the array *in reverse* and stop when you find an item with `key($item) <= $query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// in case your array keys are already sorted
$prevKey = key(current($validData));
foreach($validData as $data) {
    $currentKey = key($data);
    if ($currentKey == $query) {
        // found !
        echo $currentKey;
        break;
    }
    else if ($currentKey > $query) {
        echo $currentKey;    
        break;
    }
    $prevKey = $currentKey;
}
```

Comment: sorry didn't notice the nearest option ABOVE. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array is sorted

```
$query = 14;
$arrayThatWeWant = null;
foreach ( $validData as $index=>$vdSubRay)
{
    $ak = key($vsSubRay);
    if ( $ak == $query )
    {
        $arrayThatWeWant = $vdSubRay;
        break;
    }
    else if ( $ak > $query )
    {
        $arrayThatWeWant = $validData[$index-1];
        break;
    }
}
```